# SFAuthorizationView is unlocked with custom right

Tags: xcode, macos, authentication

I am using SFAuthorizationView to ask users authenticate with admin account so that they can get specified right.

And the right is customized by myself, already registered to system.

```
AuthorizationRightSet( authRef, myRightName, CFSTR(kAuthorizationRuleAuthenticateAsAdmin), CFSTR("Test only"), NULL, NULL);
```

And then another program acquires that right with SFAthorizationView, but the lock status is unlocked in default, and even do not ask users to authenticate in locked status.

What settings should I adjust?

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    AuthorizationItem items = {myRightName, 0, NULL, 0};
    AuthorizationRights rights = {1, &items};
    [authView setAuthorizationRights:&rights];
    authView.delegate = self;
    [authView updateStatus:nil];
}
```